# is there any way to call any method of 'send' button on MFMailComposeViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone

is there any way to call any method of 'send' button on MFMailComposeViewController in iPhone

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple explicitly forbids this. The reason being that, otherwise, your app may send mail on behalf of your users without asking them permission to do so. You could send tons of spam for instance.

The same applies to the new SMS controller available in iOS4. You can prepare the message and even setup its recipients, but it's up to the user to finally send the message.